# What library does StackOverflow use for autocomplete in tags field?

Tags: support, tags, autocomplete

What javascript library is SO using for tag autocompletion? Is it a jQuery plugin or did you write your own implementation?

(I'm asking because I'm working on a GreaseMonkey script that works on/around the tags autocompletion and I'd like to know about the options available for autocompletion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually we use this one:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: nice, I thought you said something about having issues with the autocomplete mid sentence, but notice it has the option. did you always use this puppy or switch to it?

Comment: apparently some browsers (Opera and IE) lack proper JavaScript support for full caret positioning inside text boxes. That's the only known issue.

Comment: Supposedly this works around it http://labs.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Looks like what I'm trying to do isn't going to be possible without doing additional work. (I wanted to hijack existing autocomplete code to show an autocomplete box for usernames when the user hits "@" in a comment box. I can get the list of all users active in a thread with jQuery easily enough. But there are several problems with autocomplete because the code doesn't work that well on a textarea. It's still possible, but I'll have to do a lot of work myself to create the autocomplete box.)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Is this still applicable given the changes to the auto-complete in the tag field to show more information?  Just different formatting?

Comment: Time to dump it. I think it's crapping out your whole www.stackexchange.com/filter  http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5592167#5592167