# Are there any plans to open source the tags source code as a jQuery plugin?

Tags: feature-request

I have been using [FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/) and [SmartTextBox](http://wayofspark.com/projects/smarttextbox/), but I actually like the UI (behavior and layout) of the Stack Overflow tags.  Any plans to open source this as a jQuery plugin including the ability to:

1. Have an autocomplete textbox to support mulitple entries
2. allow spaces or commas to be the seperator
3. show the tags on top of the textbox as you type and select a valid tag.

Comment: @Pekka - i updated the question with a bit more detail.  why would a tooltip plugin support this functionality ??

Comment: @ooo ah, you mean *that* part. I thought you meant the black hovering thingy (and didn't understand what that had to do with SmartTextBox)...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/what-library-does-stackoverflow-use-for-autocomplete-in-tags-field/29814#29814

Comment: @balpha - thanks for the link.  from looking at the source, the blue box of tag names that are created, is written on top of this plugin (not part of the options)

Comment: "blue box of tag names"? Do you mean the preview of the tags? Yeah, that's our own code. Probably not helpful for anyone else.

Comment: @balpha - yes, i mean the preview of the tags. i do actually think that is quite generic and useful.  Also, somehow you are able to have multiple characters as separators in the autocomplete textbox (spaces, commas, etc), how is this possible as this plugin only seems to take in a single string as the seperator ??

Comment: The preview and the autocompleter are unrelated (except that they operate with the same textbox). The preview just takes the contents of the text box and displays what the tags would look like if you submitted, but it doesn't talk to the server at all (unlike the autocompleter).

Comment: @balpha - i understand that but the preview is "listening" to keypress events or something on the autocomplete textbox by the looks of it.  also, any feedback on my question regarding the multiple seperators in my previous comments ??

Comment: @balpha -  any thoughts on my previous comment?

Comment: It might not be the plugin SE uses, but I found this one very useful and it's very customizable: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: Just modify chosen JS thats what I did. Took awhile though!

Comment: @Baconbeastnz - do you have example anywhere that can be leveraged?

Comment: Not at the moment sorry! I don't think you'll need it, their last example at http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ is basically the SE system. It's very easy/quick to implement. Modifying the source to customise your solution will take some time though it's not very well documented