# What does Stack Overflow use for its JavaScript tag suggestions?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What library does StackOverflow use for autocomplete in tags field?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/what-library-does-stackoverflow-use-for-autocomplete-in-tags-field)

Does Stack Overflow use some existing implementation for its JS tag suggestions (e.g. the drop down that shows a list of items along with a score for each when you start typing a tag), or is it custom?